# How do I create an array of method pointers in C++?

Tags: c++

How do I create an array of method pointers in C++?

The problem is, although these methods have the same signature, they are in different classes.
Those classes inherit from one same class.

For example:

```
class A : public Base {
    virtual bool work();
}

class B : public Base {
    virtual bool work();
}
```

And I need to create an array of pointers to the methods A::work and B::work, in
another class.

Edit 1:

I decided to go with Useless's suggestion, option 1:

```
vector<Base*> units;
Base *a = new A();
Base *b = new B();
units.push_back(a);
units.push_back(b);
```

Thanks

Comment: Do you have access to c++11?

Comment: Yep, we are using c++11.

Comment: Can't you just make an array of pointers to the members of the base class? Something like `bool (Base::*array)[2];`?

Comment: `bool (*Base::work)()` should be viable as long `work()` is defined in `Base`.

Comment: I have to ask: Is there a reason you aren't just making a virtual call instead of trying to utilize function pointers here?

Comment: @g-makulik except that it's a syntax error...

Comment: @g-makulik actually no, tried that but did not work.

Comment: Are you sure you're asking about your problem, and not about the solution you had in mind?

Comment: @Mark B Yes, I need to create an array of function pointers so that I can then choose one function at random.

Comment: How would you call a randomly selected function? You need to know somehow whether it's from A or from B.

Comment: Sorry, should be `bool (Base::*work)()`

Comment: Just have an array of 'Base' class pointers.  Then you can just call the virtual "work" function, after choosing a random pointer from the array.

Comment: Just to be clear, A::work and B::work don't actually have the same signature: there is an implicit A* and B* this reference argument there. Salagar's std::function is the way to go.

Comment: They do have the same signature, _if_ there is also a `virtual bool Base::work()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### First option:

if the different methods are just a implementations of the same virtual method in different subclasses, ie. `Base` looks like:

```
class Base {
public:
    virtual bool work() = 0;
}
```

Then *all* of your method pointers have type `bool (Base::*)()`. In this case, your problem is choosing an *object* to call this method on, so you presumably have a container of `Base*` pointers with different dynamic types.

---

### Second option:

your classes are really unrelated, and you just want to call some function with signature `bool (*)()` without worrying about the object.

In this case, either:

1. your classes and their instances are really irrelevant and you could just use static methods

   - so just use free functions
2. you *need* an instance but *don't* know what type it is when choosing the function

   - you need a functor which can capture the instance, and provide a compatible nullary call operator. As has already been suggested, `std::function<bool()>` is the simplest way. For example, you could populate a vector like so:

     ```
     std::vector<std::function<bool()>> fvec() {
         A a;
         B b;
         std::vector<std::function<bool()>> funcs;
         funcs.push_back( [a]() { return a.work(); } );
         funcs.push_back( [b]() { return b.work(); } );
         return funcs;
     }
     ```

     Note that the `a` and `b` objects are *captured by value* in the lambdas, so it no longer matters whether `A` and `B` have any kind of inheritance relationship.

Comment: Is this better than the approach by Edward A below?

Comment: They're pretty similar. I find the lambdas slightly more readable, but Edward could quite reasonably disagree. Also, as Salgar pointed out, you can use the Boost equivalent of Edwards code if you don't have C++11 yet.

Comment: By the way Useless, I edited my original post. Is that what you meant by your first option?

Comment: Exactly, if `work` is the only function you're going to call.

Comment: Thanks a lot, no need for std::bind or lambdas now.

Answer (score 4):

create an array (std::vector) of [std::function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function)

With `std::function` you can use [std::bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) to make a function pointer to any member function. For member functions you have to also bind to a specific instance of the object.

Here is an example of how to use it.
[std::function to member function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154116/stdfunction-to-member-function)

If you do not have c++11 access, you can do the same with `boost::bind` and `boost::function`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a combination of [`std::function`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function) and [`std::bind`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind) both of which are found in [`<functional>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional).

Example:

```
#include <functional>
#include <vector>

class Base
{
public:
    virtual bool work() = 0;
};

class A : public Base
{
public:
    bool work() {return true;}
};

class B : public Base
{
public:
    bool work() {return false;}
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::function<bool(void)>> list;

    A t1;
    B t2;

    list.push_back(std::bind(&A::work, t1));
    list.push_back(std::bind(&B::work, t2));

    for (auto& i : list)
    {
        printf("%s\n", (i()) ? "true" : "false");
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
true
false
```

Comment: Do you think this is better than the approach by Useless above?

Comment: @user2381422 As Useless said, they're fairly similar, however I don't see the point of using a lambda that calls the function, it adds levels of indirection, honestly, I find the `bind` option cleaner, this is what I'd use. Also, using `bind` + `function` means you can use all three options, lambdas, pointers, references.

Answer (score 1):

Well, technically you **can** create an array of pointers to member functions, although as others suggested, you probably shouldn't. This works:

```
class Base {
    public:
    bool work()
    {
        return true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    bool (Base::*arr[2])() = { &Base::work, &Base::work };
    return 0;
}
```