# C++ std::map Initlializator List failure

Tags: c++, dictionary, std

```
   std::map <ODParserETag ,std::function<void()>> procedure_map;
```

With

```
procedure_map = { {ODParserETag::ActorListETag, onUndefinedTag }, {ODParserETag::AdvancedWorkerETag, onUndefinedTag }, {ODParserETag::animationETag, onUndefinedTag }};
```

Fails with error :

```
/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/stl_map.h:300:7: note:   no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘std::initializer_list<std::pair<const ODParserETag, std::function<void()> > >’
```

and onU-T* is void ODParserXml::onUndefinedTag();

Is there any map container which would return some default preset value for every key  ? ( like onUndefinedTag() in this example ) ... ?

Comment: I think this kind of initialization is only done in C++11. Are you using c++11 or c++03 ?

Comment: @ArunMu as the compiler error shows `std::initializer_list`/`std::function`, you can see this is C++11. @paul any chance `onUndefinedTag` is a non-static member function of a class?

Answer (score 2):

Member functions are not functions for you can only call them with an object.

A short route would be to use a lambda-function:

```
ODParserXml parser (...);
....

procedure_map[ODParserETag::ActorListETag] = [&] { parser.onUndefinedTag(); };
```

---

See also

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154116/stdfunction-to-member-function
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7582546/using-generic-stdfunction-objects-with-member-functions-in-one-class .

---

Here's some code for tinkering (see http://ideone.com/iIEIiC):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <functional>

int main() {
    std::map<int, std::function<void()>> funs;
    funs[0] = [] { std::cout << "0\n"; };
    funs[1] = [] { std::cout << "1\n"; };

    funs[0]();
    funs[1]();
    funs[0]();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can "assign" an initializer list to an initialized variable. This calls the copy constructor on the temporary created from the braced-init-list. Also, for member functions, I got a different error on GCC 4.8.

Comment: I added static and now it works fine ! Though my second question wasn't answered , to create a container which would return default present value for all the keys ( until not redefined for a particular key ).