# How do I return a pointer to an instantiated class member function in Rcpp?

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to emulate this example [here](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/), but use a method of my own class on an instantiated object. The design choice is that I would like to make a statistical model available in R, having written the core in C++. The oo design is important to that class of problem for memory reasons. In short, it's a likelihood endowed with data and constant parameters, which then gets passed to an optimizer in R.

Because exposing classes in R is tricky when defining cluster environments, I am constructing an object inside this function and wish to return a function pointer to this very object like so:

Typedefs:

```
typedef std::function<double(int, int) > OrdinaryFunc;
typedef double (*funcPtr)(int a,int b);
```

And the two functions that collectively should enable a call to a member function:

```
  //' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
Rcpp::XPtr<OrdinaryFunc> ofunc(){

  MatrixAttempt maus(1,2,true,Eigen::MatrixXd::Zero(800,1),false,false);
  //maus.ExtraSetter(1,"Dynamic","Gaussian");
  //maus.GetModelType();

  OrdinaryFunc ofu = std::bind(&MatrixAttempt::tdens,maus,std::placeholders::_1, std::placeholders::_2);

  //return(Rcpp::XPtr<OrdinaryFunc>(new OrdinaryFunc(&ofu)));

  return(Rcpp::XPtr<OrdinaryFunc>(&ofu));

}


//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
double callViaXPtr( int a, int b, SEXP xpsexp) {
  Rcpp::XPtr<funcPtr> xpfun(xpsexp);
  funcPtr fun = *xpfun;
  double y = fun(a,b);
  return (y);
}
```

My attempt at a solution was to include a [function pointer in my class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2402579/function-pointer-to-member-function), which strikes me as unnecessarily hacky. The example provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154116/stdfunction-to-member-function) helped with creating adequate pointers to instantiated class members, so that it compiles fine. Back home in R, I ran

`fun <- ofunc()` and then `callViaXPtr(1,2,fun)` which crashed my R session with no error message.

How can I construct an instance of a class inside a wrapper function and return it as a pointer to the R session so that it can be called like a normal function?

Importantly, the function should be exportable to cluster nodes using the `parallel` package and not suffer from the lack of recognition as the modules output does.

Comment: In a package, use a specially name header file `package_types.h` (and/or one or two variants, see the Attributes vignette) which will then be pulled in by `RcppExports.cpp` making your package types visible and useable.

Comment: great thank you Dirk! But the code still seems to not work, somehow I get  the error: "use of undeclared identifier 'LogLikelihoodLowMem" although that is is very much a declared method in my class.

Comment: Look at working packages using XPtr and try to identify what they do differently.  The 'cran' org at GitHub (ie https://github.com/cran) allows you to search and XPtr is a weird enough pattern to work in searches.  And/or as always, babystep.  One class.  Don't export the class.  Use an empty function to instantiate, one to increase a counter there, one to read the counter as a scalar, one to destroy / deallocate.  Create such as existence proof.  Only _then_ make it more complicated.

Comment: Honestly, my sense is that people use R for the handling of data and then use Rcpp-exported functions to speed up for loops etc. I have a working oo c++ programme with a main but wanted to give the user the possibility to use R's optimisers on it, so you can 'play' and control. However, I am considering writing the whole thing, incl. optimisation in c++ and then export to R the very top via a simple wrapper. It's a bit of a shame and XPtr seemed perfect but I was hoping to find or be told about a simple example like the one with a simple function in the gallery, just an oo-version of it?

Comment: Also, I can only search for package names or repositories, not the source code. Is there a more advanced search function?

Comment: I worked it out using this code here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5154116/stdfunction-to-member-function and I modified the question a bit but executing the example https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/ still crashes my R session without error message, when I call callViaXPtr.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I edited the question and included my version of https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/passing-cpp-function-pointers/ . If the above example can be made to work on your machine, I would love to write this (and my other q's) up as gallery items as there is a real need in the applied stats community to use oo c++ code. I haven't found any examples of this elsewhere unless you had something in mind?

Comment: To explain the issue: the reason why R crashes is that your function `ofunc` returns a dangling pointer to memory that no longer exists.

Comment: So does that mean I should use keyword new to avoid garbage collection? However, where do I delete it then?